# How to create a public Url for an attachment?

Tags: apex, url, contentversion, fileupload, contentdistribution

I used a lightning:fileUpload to insert a file into the Attachment object:

```
<lightning:fileUpload 
     recordId="{!v.patientId}" 
     aura:id="fuploader"
     name="files" 
     multiple="false" 
     onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}"/>
```

The insertion happens fine, a progress bar opens and file is uploaded to attachment and I am getting the id of the created attachment. The problem is, I want to open the file outside of the salesforce (ie, for people who are not logged into salesforce). After some research, i found out that [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentVersion.htm) and [ContentDistribution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm) can be used to create a public url for files. So, my question is how can I generate public url for an attachment using ContentVersion or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Would this help. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/create-publicly-shared-password-protected-files-prabhat-sharma

Comment: @manjit5190 thanks for the comment. i think, for this to work, i need to get the attchment body after upload is completed. is there any way to get that?